# iOS Printing UI - limit number of copies

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, printing

is it possible to limit number of copies (from code) which user is allowed to print?

[image: iOS Printing UI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word: No.

This is not exposed in the public API and you should file a feature request on bugreport.apple.com if you want to see this functionality in a future version of the iOS APIs.