# UIPrintInteractionController - Limit print copies / Get number of printed copies

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, printing

I'm developing an iPad app that includes the ability to print a document.  Some documents require rights management wherein a limited number of copies may be printed and the number of copies printed must be recorded.

I've scoured the [UIPrintInteractionController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPrintInteractionController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation and have found no such capabilities.  This question was asked here over a year ago: [iOS Printing UI - limit number of copies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200486/ios-printing-ui-limit-number-of-copies) and at the time this feature was not available - here's hoping it has since changed.

My questions are:

1. A year later, does cocoa touch still not have the ability to limit number of copies that can be printed?
2. Is there any way to GET the number of copies printed?
3. Is one forced to use the UIPrintInteractionController?  If I'm unable to set or get copies, then I may be forced to write my own (if at all possible).

Comment: Do you know anything more about it please?

Answer (score 2):

Trying to control the number of copies a user can print using UIPrintInteractionController.
I have the same problem and I was walking home and it hit me. Why dont I just create a category for the UIStepper and override its behavior.

I dont use the UIStepper in my app so this wont effect my app, but if you do theres probably a way you can selectively apply this code.

Anyway, you want something like this:

```
@implementation UIStepper (MJStepper)

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.minimumValue = 1;
        self.maximumValue = 1;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

So create a category and include it in the same view which uses the UIPrintInteractionController

Then set the min and max values on init, and BAM. The print modal says 1 copy and has no uistepper. :)

You could set this to any number programmatically or even give the user a fixed range.

I really wish Apple had a full programmatic API for printing.
I am building a Kiosk app and the last thing I want is for the user to be able to print 100 copies of something.

I think the paper type and printer selection is still annoying but I can probably live with that.

Does anyone know if theres a way to control what Paper types your printer supports?
I know theres a delegate callback which I might be able to use to force a specific type of paper so I might try that.

Anyway, hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you Madhava.  I'm open to the idea of using categories, but not so much with overriding any 'black boxed' logic of the UIPrintInteractionController as this would adversely affect my application's app store approval.  It's been nearly a year since I've first looked into this and I have yet to see any capabilities for limiting number of print copies.  Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Well if you've been waiting a year why dont you try it and submit it. What do you have to lose? Rejection is only a week of waiting and then you can submit again. I dont really see how overriding the uistepper on print is a bad thing. Why are you trying to prevent multiple printings? Is it for some financial reason? For me its a public Kiosk issue so I think its justified.

Comment: Hi @madhava.  At that point in time I was researching the development effort involved in implementing such a feature.  Ultimately we've opted for a different approach.  Yes, in a manner of speaking this was for financial reasons.  Specifically, the user was restricted to number of purchased copies.  Thanks.