# UIPrintInteractionController set minimum number of copies

Tags: ios, xamarin, printing, xamarin.ios, uiprintinteractioncntrler

I'd like to know if there's a way to set a minimum number of copies to be printed via code, because I need a document to be printed by duplicate.

I read the documentation on Apple developers page but I couldn't find anything.

I know you can set the number of copies from the printer dialog, but I need the minimum to be 2 by default.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670529/uiprintinteractioncontroller-limit-print-copies-get-number-of-printed-copies) and it didn't work for me, at least in Xamarin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIPrintInteractionController - Limit print copies / Get number of printed copies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670529/uiprintinteractioncontroller-limit-print-copies-get-number-of-printed-copies). You should be able to port this to Xamarin, but be aware that the solution is undocumented (double check if this is using a private API before submitting to the App Store).

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing exposed via `UIPrintInteractionController` or its delegates that allows you to change/override the number of copies.

The way I approach this is to write my own `UIController` that defines the properties that the user is allowed to change and then use `UIPrintInteractionController.PrintToPrinter` to directly print the content.

Another approach is to disable the number of copies display:

```
UIPrintInteractionController.ShowsNumberOfCopies = false;
```

And then provide a two element array to `PrintingItems` vs. `PrintingItem` that just contains two copies of your print object.

Another approach just allow the user to select the printer via `UIPrinterPickerController`, save the `UIPrinter` to skip it in the future and then call `PrintToPrinter` twice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try this and let you know how this goes.